# how to really hide HTML div element using css or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide div element located in bootstraps radio or checkbox container,
this is how it look using jquery:

I can't post image, so prev is here: http://prntscr.com/6wrk2m

```
<style>
.my-radio{
border: 1px solid #F0F;
}
</style>
<div class="radio my-radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x1" onClick="$('#qq').toggleClass('hide')" />1
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio my-radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x2" onClick="$('#qq').toggleClass('hide')" />2
    </label>
</div>
<div id="qq">8-bit pork belly Echo Park scenester</div>
<div class="radio my-radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x3" onClick="$('#qq').toggleClass('hide')" />3
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio my-radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x2" onClick="$('#qq').toggleClass('hide')" />2
    </label>
</div>
```

display:none doesn't work too ...

Comment: try `opacity:0;` or  `height:0;width:0`

Comment: if you are using `bootstrap` try giving the class `hidden`

Comment: I don't see a CSS directive for `.hide`.

Comment: Bootstrap make this space between labels ... Do You know where in bootstrap.css I can correct it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways. You can do this by

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

or even by this class:

```
.hide {
    border: 0 none;
    clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Check this example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5yoz79w/3/)

Comment: no, it doesn't work, like I said, display:none doesn't work too

Comment: What styles do You have under `hide` class?

Comment: @MacUmatik Check my post update. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, note the addition of classes and the use of an event handler instead of the inline javascript:

```js
$(function() {
 
  $('.hideOnClick').click(function(){
      $('#qq').toggle();
    
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.my-radio{
border: 1px solid #F0F;
}
</style>
<div class="radio my-radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x1" class="hideOnClick" />1
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio my-radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x2" class="hideOnClick"  />2
    </label>
</div>
<div id="qq">8-bit pork belly Echo Park scenester</div>
<div class="radio my-radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x3" class="hideOnClick" />3
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio my-radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" id="x2" class="hideOnClick" />2
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i just did using jquery:

```
$('#qq').hide();
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

in CSS you can hide an element simply by changing it's css display property to none. simply use `display:none` and there you go :)
as for jquery solution you can use hide() method. here is a full example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**update:**
i personally prefer just overriding css using a java code.wrap this code in a function and add onclick to your button or your checkbox with the refrece of function you just made

```js
document.getElementById("qq").setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```